# FFMPEG AAC encoding causes audio to be lower in pitch

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-recording, aac, portaudio

I built a sample application that encodes AAC (from PortAudio) into a MP4 container (no video stream).

The resulting audio is lower in pitch.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestRecording.h"
#include "libffmpeg.h"

TestRecording::TestRecording()
{
}


TestRecording::~TestRecording()
{
}

struct RecordingContext
{
    RecordingContext()
    {
        formatContext = NULL;
        audioStream = NULL;
        audioFrame = NULL;
        audioFrameframeNumber = 0;
    }

    libffmpeg::AVFormatContext* formatContext;
    libffmpeg::AVStream* audioStream;
    libffmpeg::AVFrame* audioFrame;
    int audioFrameframeNumber;
};

static int AudioRecordCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
    unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void *userData)
{
    RecordingContext* recordingContext = (RecordingContext*)userData;

    libffmpeg::avcodec_fill_audio_frame(recordingContext->audioFrame,
        recordingContext->audioFrame->channels,
        recordingContext->audioStream->codec->sample_fmt,
        static_cast<const unsigned char*>(inputBuffer),
        (framesPerBuffer * sizeof(float) * recordingContext->audioFrame->channels),
        0);

    libffmpeg::AVPacket pkt;
    libffmpeg::av_init_packet(&pkt);
    pkt.data = NULL;
    pkt.size = 0;

    int gotpacket;
    int result = avcodec_encode_audio2(recordingContext->audioStream->codec, &pkt, recordingContext->audioFrame, &gotpacket);

    if (result < 0)
    {
        LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't encode the audio frame to acc");
        return paContinue;
    }

    if (gotpacket)
    {
        pkt.stream_index = recordingContext->audioStream->index;
        recordingContext->audioFrameframeNumber++;

        // this codec requires no bitstream filter, just send it to the muxer!
        result = libffmpeg::av_write_frame(recordingContext->formatContext, &pkt);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            LOG(ERROR) << "Couldn't write the encoded audio frame";
            libffmpeg::av_free_packet(&pkt);
            return paContinue;
        }

        libffmpeg::av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }

    return paContinue;
}

static bool InitializeRecordingContext(RecordingContext* recordingContext)
{
    int result = libffmpeg::avformat_alloc_output_context2(&recordingContext->formatContext, NULL, NULL, "C:\\Users\\Paul\\Desktop\\test.mp4");
    if (result < 0)
    {
        LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't create output format context");
        return false;
    }

    libffmpeg::AVCodec *audioCodec;
    audioCodec = libffmpeg::avcodec_find_encoder(libffmpeg::AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
    if (audioCodec == NULL)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Couldn't find the encoder for AAC";
    }

    recordingContext->audioStream = libffmpeg::avformat_new_stream(recordingContext->formatContext, audioCodec);
    if (!recordingContext->audioStream)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Couldn't create the audio stream";
        return false;
    }

    recordingContext->audioStream->codec->bit_rate = 64000;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codec->sample_fmt = libffmpeg::AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codec->sample_rate = 48000;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codec->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codec->channels = libffmpeg::av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(recordingContext->audioStream->codec->channel_layout);

    recordingContext->audioStream->codecpar->bit_rate = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->bit_rate;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codecpar->format = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->sample_fmt;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codecpar->sample_rate = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->sample_rate;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codecpar->channel_layout = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->channel_layout;
    recordingContext->audioStream->codecpar->channels = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->channels;

    result = libffmpeg::avcodec_open2(recordingContext->audioStream->codec, audioCodec, NULL);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't open the audio codec");
        return false;
    }

    // create a new frame to store the audio samples
    recordingContext->audioFrame = libffmpeg::av_frame_alloc();
    if (!recordingContext->audioFrame)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Couldn't alloce the output audio frame";
        return false;
    }

    recordingContext->audioFrame->nb_samples = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->frame_size;
    recordingContext->audioFrame->channel_layout = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->channel_layout;
    recordingContext->audioFrame->channels = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->channels;
    recordingContext->audioFrame->format = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->sample_fmt;
    recordingContext->audioFrame->sample_rate = recordingContext->audioStream->codec->sample_rate;

    result = libffmpeg::av_frame_get_buffer(recordingContext->audioFrame, 0);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Coudln't initialize the output audio frame buffer";
        return false;
    }

    // some formats want video_stream headers to be separate  
    if (!strcmp(recordingContext->formatContext->oformat->name, "mp4") || !strcmp(recordingContext->formatContext->oformat->name, "mov") || !strcmp(recordingContext->formatContext->oformat->name, "3gp"))
    {
        recordingContext->audioStream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }

    // open the ouput file
    if (!(recordingContext->formatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        result = libffmpeg::avio_open(&recordingContext->formatContext->pb, recordingContext->formatContext->filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't open the output file");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // write the stream headers
    result = libffmpeg::avformat_write_header(recordingContext->formatContext, NULL);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't write the headers to the file");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static bool FinalizeRecordingContext(RecordingContext* recordingContext)
{
    int result = 0;

    // write the trailing information
    if (recordingContext->formatContext->pb)
    {
        result = libffmpeg::av_write_trailer(recordingContext->formatContext);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't write the trailer information");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // close all the codes
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)recordingContext->formatContext->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        result = libffmpeg::avcodec_close(recordingContext->formatContext->streams[i]->codec);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't close the codec");
            return false;
        }
    }

    // close the output file
    if (recordingContext->formatContext->pb)
    {
        if (!(recordingContext->formatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        {
            result = libffmpeg::avio_close(recordingContext->formatContext->pb);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't close the output file");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // free the format context and all of its data
    libffmpeg::avformat_free_context(recordingContext->formatContext);

    recordingContext->formatContext = NULL;
    recordingContext->audioStream = NULL;

    if (recordingContext->audioFrame)
    {
        libffmpeg::av_frame_free(&recordingContext->audioFrame);
        recordingContext->audioFrame = NULL;
    }

    return true;
}

int TestRecording::Test()
{
    PaError result = paNoError;

    result = Pa_Initialize();
    if (result != paNoError) LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Error initializing audio device framework");

    RecordingContext recordingContext;
    if (!InitializeRecordingContext(&recordingContext))
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Couldn't start recording file";
        return 0;
    }

    auto defaultDevice = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();
    auto deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(defaultDevice);

    PaStreamParameters  inputParameters;
    inputParameters.device = defaultDevice;
    inputParameters.channelCount = 2;
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = paFloat32;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = deviceInfo->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    PaStream* stream = NULL;
    result = Pa_OpenStream(
        &stream,
        &inputParameters,
        NULL,
        48000,
        1024,
        paClipOff,
        AudioRecordCallback,
        &recordingContext);
    if (result != paNoError)LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't open the audio stream");

    result = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (result != paNoError)LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't start the audio stream");

    Sleep(1000 * 5);

    result = Pa_StopStream(stream);
    if (result != paNoError)LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't stop the audio stream");

    if (!FinalizeRecordingContext(&recordingContext)) LOG(ERROR) << "Couldn't stop recording file";

    result = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    if (result != paNoError)LOGINT_WITH_MESSAGE(ERROR, result, "Couldn't stop the audio stream");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the `stdout`, in case it helps.

https://gist.github.com/pauldotknopf/9f24a604ce1f8a081aa68da1bf169e98

Why is the audio lower in pitch? I assume I am overlooking a parameter that needs to be configured between PortAudio and FFMPEG. Is there something super obvious that I am missing?

Comment: You're sample output shows 48000 and 44100 sample rates...

Comment: Those are just defaults, when PortAudio does it's scan of devices.